# The file upload in feeds importer is not working

Tags: 6, feeds, importing-exporting

I have been reading through all the documentation I can find, but I cant find a simple solution for this problem.

I can upload the first CSV file, and import it to a custom table with error handling and everything; when I try to upload the second CSV file, the importer imports the first file and the new file is not even uploaded to my server.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

So I have still been working on this issue and this is what seems to be happening. I "upload" a local file, this file is not actually uploaded to the server and is not recorded in the database in the "feeds_source," or in the "files" tables. The only available file is the original file that had been uploaded, and this file is being re-imported into the database. This is why I am not getting any errors or warnings or watchdog reports.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by increasing the PHP upload limit, and the memory limit.